# direct sql query in custom module

Tags: php, magento2.3, rest-api, resource-model

I have created a new web API module, this API should execute a direct SQL query.

This is the code:

```
namespace Mymodule\ProductByEbayItemid\Model\ProductByEbayItemidQuery;

class ProductByEbayItemidQuery {
    protected $_resourceConnection;
    protected $_connection;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    ) {
        $this->_resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    }
    public function getProductid($ebayitemid)
    {   
        $this->_connection = $this->_resourceConnection->getConnection();
        //Your custom sql query
        $query = "SELECT product_id FROM etbrm2epro_ebay_item WHERE item_id=:item_id";
        $binds = array ( 'item_id' =>  $ebayitemid );
        $collection = $this->_connection->fetchOne( $query,$binds );
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to instance this class in the API class.

```
namespace EternalParquet\ProductByEbayItemid\Model;
use EternalParquet\ProductByEbayItemid\Api\ProductByEbayItemidInterface;

class ProductByEbayItemid implements ProductByEbayItemidInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns product data by ebay item id,
     * if m2epro is not installed it return null.
     * @ebayitemid ebay item id
     * @api
     * @return product data.
     */
    public function get($ebayitemid) {
             //?????
    }
}
```

> acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="EternalParquet_ProductByEbayItemid::productid" title="GetProductByEbayItemid" translate="title" sortOrder="110" />
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="EternalParquet\ProductByEbayItemid\Api\ProductByEbayItemidInterface"
                type="EternalParquet\ProductByEbayItemid\Model\ProductByEbayItemid" />
</config>
```

> webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/productByEbayItemid/productid/:ebayitemid" method="GET">
        <service class="EternalParquet\ProductByEbayItemid\Api\ProductByEbayItemidInterface" method="productid"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="EternalParquet_ProductByEbayItemid::productid"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Comment: I changed get method to productid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no , the paths are like for interface and model should be like  :
`app\code\EternalParquet\ProductByEbayItemid\Api\ProductByEbayItemidInterface`
and 
`app\code\EternalParquet\ProductByEbayItemid\Model\ProductByEbayItemidQuery`.
you should specify parameters before the function

```
/**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param mixed $ebayitemid ID.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
```

Comment: I get always this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Call the interface and model in the webapi.xml in the below format

```
<route url="/V1/account/getproductid" method="GET">
        <service class="EternalParquet\ProductByEbayItemid\Api\ProductByEbayItemidInterface" method="getProductid"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

and in di.xml

```
 <preference for="EternalParquet\ProductByEbayItemid\Api\ProductByEbayItemidInterface" type="Mymodule\ProductByEbayItemid\Model\ProductByEbayItemidQuery" />
```

the method and parameters should be same in API interface and model

Comment: These classes are in the same directory

Comment: I get this error:
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\\Framework\\Reflection\\TypeProcessor::resolveFullyQualifiedClassName() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php on line 535 and defined in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php:640\nStack trace:\n#0 ......